# Capture "wheel" event on KonvaJS Stage only once

Tags: konvajs

I want to execute a function in the context of a "wheel" event from a KonvaJS Stage, only once.

Is there a sort of "idiomatic" way of achieving this in Konvajs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
stage.on('wheel', () => {
  console.log('wheel');
  stage.off('wheel');
})
```

Comment: Many thanks Anton, as elegant as your library :-)